# What is accessible in Monaco during the Formula 1 races?

Tags: monaco, formula-one

As I understand it, the Monte Carlo Casino is closed during the races. Is that correct? When does it open? Is it closed only on Sundays or during practice times (e.g. Thursday noon), as well?

Are you at least able to see how it looks from somewhere?

Lastly, can I wander around the area in Monte Carlo where the Opera House and Casino are located?

Edit: http://www.casinomontecarlo.com/plan-your-stay/casino-entry/

From website
"Groups and tours: Every day, except during the Formula 1 Grand Prix, the Casino de Monte-Carlo is open to groups and tours from 9 am till 12 pm only, so that games aren't disturbed."

Would you then say that Monte Carlo is open (after 2PM) for playing even during the races? Only tours are not happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would like to share my experience while visiting Monaco during F1. I was there on the 25th of May (Thursday) on first half of the day (practice session - track closed) and on the 26th (Friday) during second half of day (track opened to public). The schedule during these days can be found here https://www.monaco-grand-prix.com/en/programme-2542-f1-monaco-451.html

Monte Carlo casino was **closed** during F1 practice and, in fact, any other time when track was used and would be reopened around 19:00. This included whole area around the casino. Only Café de Paris was accessible. Additionally it was not possible to get a nice view of the Monte Carlo on Thursday. It is, however, when track is opened to the public.

Tourist places were open on Friday, however, for example, Prince's Palace of Monaco could be visited only until 15:00 (usually at least 18:00) and it was closed on Saturday and Sunday.

In general I would advise any visitor willing to explore Monaco during F1 to contact their tourist info center before.

Answer (score 5):

From the Monte Carlo casino website, there is no mention about being closed during F1 weekend: it is opened everyday from 2PM. So it must be opened.

I hope you already have your hotel and don't want to use your car as the circuit is really in the main streets:
[image: Map of Monaco with F1 circuit]

But you will probably be able to walk around the city if your are 1 block away from the track.

In addition, as @AndyT commented:

> They also open all the roads up every evening, after whatever
>   practice/qualifying/race sessions have finished.  (Source: my
>   brother-in-law who went to the Monaco GP a couple of years ago.)

Comment: They also open all the roads up every evening, after whatever practice/qualifying/race sessions have finished. (Source: my brother-in-law who went to the Monaco GP a couple of years ago.)

Comment: added in the response with quote ;)

Comment: "Groups and tours:
Every day, except during the Formula 1 Grand Prix, the Casino de Monte-Carlo is open to groups and tours from 9 am till 12 pm only, so that games aren't disturbed."

Comment: @Mefistofelis so maybe add that you want to take a tour of the Casino and not simply go to the casino to play

Comment: Sorry, I just got very confused. People say that things are not accessible/closed.. But I think you made me realize what they mean with the closure! Thank you for the answer!

Comment: No problem, don't hesitate to add more context at the beginning of your questions ;)